# CSS: How to adjust space between list elements

Tags: css, list

I try to edit CSS for a list but I did not find how to go to line and to adjust height between list elements properly.

Link to the website : https://denkimedia.com/prod/K2211001/test/

[menu open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRiL6.png)

But I don't know how to fix the size between the list elements :

[Display list is not ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phzEL.png)

Any idea? :)

I modified position and white-space in article-verticle.css for adjusting the line.

`.flowpaper-reflow-tocitem{ position:relative; white-space: normal;`

padding, margin, height did not work for adjusting the space between lines.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and then edit your question using the snippet button to create a [mcve]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please apply below CSS:

```
li.flowpaper-reflow-tocitem-listitem {
    margin-left: -13px !important;
    min-height: 38px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background: #4f84eb;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

li.flowpaper-reflow-tocitem-listitem .flowpaper-reflow-tocitem {
    font-family: Lato;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 12px;
    white-space: break-spaces;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
```

You will get this result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEnPs.png

Please let me know if you find any issues

Comment: I am happy that it's worked for you. Thanks for confirmation